# How do I use .woff fonts for my website?

Tags: html, css, fonts, woff

Where do you place fonts so that CSS can access them?

I am using non-standard fonts for the browser in a .woff file. Let's say its 'awesome-font' stored in a file 'awesome-font.woff'.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

After generation of WOFF files, you have to define [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family), which can be used later in all your css styles. Below is the code to define font families (for normal, bold, bold-italic, italic) typefaces. It is assumed, that there are 4 *.WOFF files (for mentioned typefaces), placed in `fonts` subdirectory.

In CSS code:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "myfont";
  src: url("fonts/awesome-font.woff") format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "myfont";
  src: url("fonts/awesome-font-bold.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "myfont";
  src: url("fonts/awesome-font-boldoblique.woff") format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "myfont";
  src: url("fonts/awesome-font-oblique.woff") format('woff');
  font-style: italic;
}
```

After having that definitions, you can just write, for example,

In HTML code:

```html
<div class="mydiv">
    <b>this will be written with awesome-font-bold.woff</b>
    <br/>
    <b><i>this will be written with awesome-font-boldoblique.woff</i></b>
    <br/>
    <i>this will be written with awesome-font-oblique.woff</i>
    <br/>
    this will be written with awesome-font.woff
</div>
```

In CSS code:

```css
.mydiv {
  font-family: myfont
}
```

The good tool for generation WOFF files, which can be included in CSS stylesheets is located [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator). Not all WOFF files work correctly under latest Firefox versions, and this generator produces 'correct' fonts.

Comment: Can you please explain how material icons work; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323577/how-md-icons-are-rendered-on-browser

Answer (score 22):

You need to declare `@font-face` like this in your stylesheet

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Awesome-Font';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Awesome-Font'), local('Awesome-Font-Regular'), url(path/Awesome-Font.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Now if you want to apply this font to a paragraph simply use it like this..

```
p {
font-family: 'Awesome-Font', Arial;
}
```

[**More Reference**](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/at-fontface)

Comment: for the src tag how does one use rel="preload" for the woff file in this case?