# targeting a specific browser with css

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser

i guess that firefox is the only browser that doesn't support the font "Arial Narrow". And the other browsers don't support the "font-stretch" property. How can I target a specific browser with CSS? I have done this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h2 {
  font-family:"Arial";
  font-stretch: condensed;
    }
    .header_p {
  font-family: "Arial";
  font-stretch: condensed;
}

}
h2{
 font-family:"Arial Narrow";
 font-size: 22px;
 letter-spacing: 0px;
}

.header_p {
 font-family: "Arial Narrow";
}
```

It isn't working and I don't know why..

If I swap the order so that the @-moz part is second, then chrome stops working. I guess it's trying to apply the @-moz rule

And IE doesn't read the CSS at all

Comment: Works just fine in my Chrome 34, IE 11 and FF 29: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/eRquy/

Comment: thanks. i actually left out a curly bracket, which i see someone edited. and now it does work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether that font family is supported by firefox or not but you can 
Target only **firefox** using

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    h1 {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

See complete documentation **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions)**

You can target **IE** as

```
<!--[if IE]>
  // Your css for IE or   
  // Perhaps importing a specific style sheet as
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie9_and_below.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

target **chrome** only

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
 div{
      color: red;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the much missed [H Open Magazine](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/WOFF-Now-loading-fonts-on-websites-1047073.html):

CSS3 includes [a font module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-fonts-20090618/) which offers an **@font-face** declaration, allowing web developers to load fonts to ensure that their website displays with the right font. WOFF is the data format for these fonts.

A file format specifically designed for the web, it is a container which, as well as the (optionally compressed) font tables in sfnt format, can also contain metadata, such as licensing or other information.

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/woff) is near universal.

Here's [an example of how to use them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812441/how-do-i-use-woff-fonts-for-my-website).

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below snippet.

```
  h2 {
        font-family: "Arial Narrow";
        font-size: 22px;
        letter-spacing: 0px;
    }

    .header_p {
        font-family: "Arial Narrow";
    }

    h2, x:-moz-any-link {
        font-family: "Arial";
        font-stretch: condensed;
    }

    .header_p, x:-moz-any-link {
        font-family: "Arial";
        font-stretch: condensed;
    }
```