# How to add custom css font icons in Oracle APEX 5

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex

I have been surfing through the sites looking for a way to add my custom css font icons for my own application.
I have uploaded the css file in the workspace static files, and put the url in Shared Components\ Themes \ Icons \ Custom Library File URLs.

Please show my how to used my custom css font icons, for I don't want to upload images or so.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your version, but Maxime has an example here describing how to import Font APEX library for APEX 5.0

http://max-tremblay.blogspot.com.au/2017/02/using-font-apex-in-apex-50.html

You're chasing attributes in the theme settings.

Answer (score 0):

Fonts like **[Wingdings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingdings)** render letters as a variety of symbols. If you look at some font websites likes **[dafont](https://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=721)**, you can see a lot of symbol fonts. Download the font file (ttf) and convert it to **[woff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Open_Font_Format)** using some converter tool / websites like **[convertio](https://convertio.co/ttf-woff/)**. You may refer [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812441/how-do-i-use-woff-fonts-for-my-website) to get an idea about its usage in CSS.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think the OP already has icons, they just want to integrate them within the APEX environment